# What rules turn any attack that hits a given target into a critical hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, critical-hit

As the title says, what rules are there that make any attack that hits a given target deal damage as if it were a critical hit? I thought I remembered hearing something about that and the prone condition but after double checking it, it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of all effects that do this, or are you asking if there is one at all?

Comment: If there are any rules that do it I would like a list of effects that do it, otherwise then just saying that there aren't any that do it works.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Paralyzed and Unconscious both produce automatic crits

With the caveat that you have to be within short range, however.

From the Players Handbook -

Page 291

> **Paralyzed**
>
> A paralyzed creature is incapacitated (see the condition) and can’t move or speak.
> • The creature automatically fails Strength and Dexterity saving throws.
> • Attack rolls against the creature have advantage.
> • **Any attack that hits the creature is a critical hit if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature**.

Page 292

> **Unconscious**
>
> • An unconscious creature is incapacitated (see the condition), can’t move or speak, and is unaware of its surroundings.
> • The creature drops whatever it’s holding and falls prone.
> • The creature automatically fails Strength and Dexterity saving throws.
> • Attack rolls against the creature have advantage.
> • **Any attack that hits the creature is a critical hit if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature.**

Additionally as noted by @Allan Mills (Thank you!), an assassin archetype rogue will also gain the automatic critical with hits on surprised opponents, starting at 3rd level.

> **Assassinate**
>
> Starting at 3rd level, you are at your deadliest when you get the drop on your enemies. You have advantage on attack rolls against any creature that hasn't taken a turn in the combat yet. **In addition, any hit you score against a creature that is surprised is a critical hit.**

Comment: Stunned condition?

Comment: @tuskiomi no, stunned only gives advantage on attack rolls. The condition doesn't say anything about automatic crits.

Comment: @JohnP I thought it stuff that a stunned creature is paralyzed

Comment: @tuskiomi - Not as I understand it, no. A stunned creature still has power of speech, for example. The condition description does not state the auto crit, where it is specifically spelled out for paralyzed/unconscious.

Answer (score 13):

## Paralyzed and Unconscious Conditions do this

Any creature that suffers the effects of the [Paralyzed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Paralyzed) or [Unconscious](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Unconscious) condition converts any attack successfully delivered within 5' to a critical hit:

> Any attack that hits the creature is a critical hit if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature.

There are many ways in which you can get that condition, but it is the condition itself that mechanically changes a regular hit to a critical hit.

Answer (score 7):

**Rogue Assassin Archetype Assassinate Feature grants critical hits to surprised enemies**

From the **Assassinate** feature from the Assassin Rogue archetype:

> In addition, any hit you score against a creature that is surprised is a critical hit.

This isn't every attack however it does grant criticals without having to roll a 20 (or 18/19 if multiclassed into Champion)